# SQL Selecting with 2 entries in 1 table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with Names and university courses, with each course registered being a different entry in the table

```
NAME       COURSE
StudA      Bio
StudA      Maths
StudB      Maths
StudC      Bio
StudC      Maths
```

How can I select all students registered for both Bio and Maths? I Tried

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Course = 'Bio' And Course = 'Maths' GROUP BY Name;
```

But I get no results.

I need BOTH the results to the same student. i.e Only StudA and B should be given as they are registred for BOTH courses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you mean, are you looking for students registered for both math and bio, or for student registered in either of them?

-- Student registered on both math and bio

```
 select NAME 
 from T
 where Course IN('Bio', 'Maths')
 group by NAME
 having count( distinct COURSE ) = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `OR` instead of `AND`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table 
WHERE Course = 'Bio' OR Course = 'Maths' 
GROUP BY Name;
```

`AND` returns records with Course='Bio' **and** 'Maths' (which won't happen at the same time).

Example in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e34bd/5).

If you are looking for students who appear for both courses:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableName 
WHERE Course = 'Bio' OR Course = 'Maths' 
GROUP BY Name
HAVING COUNT(*)=2
```

Example in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e34bd/6).

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but dont you think that it also fetches a record that does not have any one of those courses.

Comment: @Ravinder: Yes, but only when that student appear for 'Bio' or 'Maths'. If he is appearing for courses which are not in these, it won't be fetched. See [**this**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e34bd/2).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the IN clause:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Course IN ('Bio', 'Maths') GROUP BY Name;
```

It checks whether the column value corresponds to the one in the presented list.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Course IN('Bio', 'Maths') GROUP BY Name;
```

Try this please.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `GROUP BY` but with `HAVING COUNT(*)=2` condition so in this case you select students registered for both classes:

```
SELECT Name 
 FROM Table 
WHERE Course = 'Bio' or Course = 'Maths' 
GROUP BY Name
HAVING COUNT(*)=2
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c1d510/1)</kbd>